# Feedback em um drag drop

Tags: jquery, html5, jquery-ui, drag-n-drop

Fiz um *drag-n-drop* com o *jQuery*, mas quero que quando a pessoa preencher todos apareça um feedback, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso, segue um exemplo do meu código

```
<img src="image.png" class="card01">
<img src="image.png" class="card02">
<div class="bloco01"></div>
<div class="bloco02"></div>
<div class-"feedback"></div>"

$( function() {
    $( ".card01" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
    $( ".bloco01" ).droppable({
        accept: ".card01",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
            $( ".card01" ).addClass('dropped');
        }
    });

    $( ".card02" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
    $( ".bloco02" ).droppable({
        accept: ".card02",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
            $( ".card02" ).addClass('dropped');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Preencher todos o que?? Vc tem div e img, o que tem ai para preencher? Sua pergunta não ficou clara

Comment: Editei o código, eu quero que ao inserir todas imagens nas divs correspondentes,apareça uma mensagem na classe feedback, por exemplo parabéns você preencheu tudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você adiciona uma classe aos cards, daí basta você fazer uma condicional para ver se os mesmos tem as classes. Se tiverem as classes mostra a mensagem ao usuário, senão tiverem a mensagem não é mostrada. *Deste modo, tanto faz a ordem que o usuário arrastar os elementos, só mostrará a mensagem se as duas imagens forem arrastadas:*

```js
$(function() {
  $(".card01").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".bloco01").droppable({
    accept: ".card01",
    drop: function() {
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      $(".card01").addClass("dropped");
      showMessage();
    }
  });

  $(".card02").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".bloco02").droppable({
    accept: ".card02",
    drop: function() {
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      $(".card02").addClass("dropped");
      showMessage()
    }
  });
  
  $(".card03").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".bloco03").droppable({
    accept: ".card03",
    drop: function() {
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      $(".card03").addClass("dropped");
      showMessage();
    }
  });
  
  $(".card04").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".bloco04").droppable({
    accept: ".card04",
    drop: function() {
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      $(".card04").addClass("dropped");
      showMessage();
    }
  });
  
});

function showMessage() {
    var card01 = $(".card01").hasClass("dropped");
    var card02 = $(".card02").hasClass("dropped");;
    var card03 = $(".card03").hasClass("dropped");;
    var card04 = $(".card04").hasClass("dropped");;
    
    if(card01 && card02 && card03 && card04) {
        $(".feedback").addClass("show");
    }
  }
```

```css
.bloco01 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.bloco02, .bloco04 {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.bloco02{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bloco03{
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: green;
}

.bloco04{
  background-color: gray;
}

.card01, .card02, .card03, .card04 {
  z-index: 999;
}

.feedback {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}

.ui-state-highlight {
  border: solid 5px blue;
}

.dropped {
  border: solid 3px blue;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: showFeed 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes showFeed {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<img src="image.png" class="card01">
<img src="image.png" class="card02">
<img src="image.png" class="card03">
<img src="image.png" class="card04">
<div class="bloco01"></div>
<div class="bloco02"></div>
<div class="bloco03"></div>
<div class="bloco04"></div>
<div class="feedback">Você preencheu todos!</div>
```

> **O Css foi só para ilustrar.**

Comment: Mas e se eu tiver mais de 2 drag drop, por exemplo 6 cards e 6 blocos, fiz o teste mas ele sempre só pega os 2 primeiros

Comment: Editei a resposta. O que fiz basicamente foi, criar uma função para verificar se os elementos tem a classe **dropped** e chamar a função a cada **droppable**.